# Override eslint settings in non-ejected create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, overriding, create-react-app, eslint

I've found a ton of "solutions" for this, ranging from simple package.json additions to custom hack modules, but none worked for me.

I simply want to override the eslint settings for an out-of-the-box, NON ejected create-react-app.

Namely, the rule "no-unused-vars".

I'm using Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I seem to have fixed this accidentally just trying combinations of things I found online. This seems to have worked.

1) I created a .env file in the project root (where the package.json file is). In it I have:

```
// .env file

EXTEND_ESLINT = true
```

2) Then I created a .eslintrc file (no extension) in my project root and added this:

```
// .eslintrc file (no extension)
{
  "extends": [
    "react-app"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": "off"
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, restart your `create-react-app` if you haven't already. I'm really disappointed by how much digging I had to find to disable this one setting, thanks for posting your solution.

Comment: The kicker seems to be the `EXTEND_ESLINT = true` in `.env`. After I did that, I could use `eslinConfig` in my `package.json`. THX a lot.

Comment: **NOTE** [`EXTEND_ESLINT flag was removed in react-scripts v4`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes) as it is no longer required to customise the ESLint config

Answer (score 4):

In the `create-react-app` project `package.json` is ready, you just need to add the `rules` field.

**`package.json`**

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest"
  ],
+ "rules": {
+    "react/self-closing-comp": 1
+  }
},
```

**[It's important to note that any rules that are set to "error" will stop the project from building.](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#extending-or-replacing-the-default-eslint-config)**

`create-react-app` uses `eslint-config-react-app`, which contains almost all popular eslint packages.

- `eslint-plugin-flowtype`
- `eslint-plugin-import`
- `eslint-plugin-jest`
- `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y`
- `eslint-plugin-react`
- `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`
- `eslint-plugin-testing-library`

`eslint-config-react-app github`
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/main/packages/eslint-config-react-app

`eslint-config-react-app npm`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-react-app

Answer (score 2):

The library now supports extending the pre-defined ESLint rules natively, see [the relevant docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#experimental-extending-the-eslint-config).

---

The gist of it is that you will have to set the `EXTEND_ESLINT` environment variable, and then add your own ESLint config to the project root, optionally extending create-react-app's:

```
{
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": ["react-app"],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": ["**/*.js"],
        "rules": {
          "no-unused-vars": "warn"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

its not hard, just follow these steps:

1. `npm i -D eslint eslint-plugin-react`
2. `npx eslint --init`
3. edit the generated config file, for example `.eslintrc.json`
4. put your rules in the `"rules": { ... }` section

Comment: broke my CRA "Failed to load config "react-app" to extend from"
fixed with:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66052385/724910