# Failed to load config "react" to extend from

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, eslint

I am trying to create a react app without using create-react-app using the following website:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-set-up-deploy-your-react-app-from-scratch-using-webpack-and-babel-a669891033d4/

however, I keep getting this error that says

WARNING in ./src/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to load config "react" to extend from.

I have tried installing all the dependencies and have spent hours googling an answer, but I can't seem to figure out the problem.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.js\"",
    "eslint-fix": "eslint --fix \"src/**/*.js\"",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.9.0",
    "eslint-config-react": "^1.1.7",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.4.1",
    "less": "^3.12.2",
    "less-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "prettier": "2.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

this is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      // path: __dirname + '/dist',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
      contentBase: './build'
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'less-loader',
        ],
      }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: path.resolve('./index.html'),
        })],
  };
```

this is my .eslintrc:

```
  {
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": "react",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my .babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
  }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? I am wracking my brain trying to figure this out and I am having a lot of trouble. It loads the webpage, however, react isn't utilized at all.

Thank you in advance!! I really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 89):

I had a similar problem with `create-react-app` and I did

```sh
yarn add eslint-config-react-app -D
```

I think you should try:

```sh
yarn add eslint-config-react -D
```

Comment: The first line `yarn add eslint-config-react-app -D` worked. The second line is shorter and doesn't have `-app` and it didn't work for me.

Comment: It depends on what you have used in your project, if react-app then it will work for you and in this question user have not used react-app then the second line would work for him.

Comment: `yarn add -D eslint-config-react-app babel-eslint` worked like magic for me

Comment: You should not do this as creat-react-app comes with it.

Answer (score 64):

When I removed

```
  "extends": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
```

from `package.json` it worked.

This is because the `eslint-config-react-app` package is outdated.

Comment: With what version of `react-scripts` is `eslint-config-react-app` outdated?

Answer (score 23):

I had this error after a big upgrade of dependencies (`react-scripts`, `react` ... ) and the solution was to remove `yarn.lock` files

Answer (score 18):

If you have `eslint` in your dependencies, remove that.
The `eslint` from `react-scripts` will be used

```json
"eslint": "^7.32.0"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was almost going crazy over this issue on webstorm and your solution has worked!

Comment: This is the best option to use with `react: 18.2.0`, and `react-scripts: "5.0.1`, which happens to be the latest version at the time of this comment. Removing `"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },` from `package.json` file works perfectly well. The eslint from `react-scripts would be used`

Comment: This actually seems at the best fix out the ones listed on this page since it fixes the root cause rather than adding an workaround

Answer (score 12):

I fix it installing `eslint-config-react-app` package manually:

```sh
yarn add eslint-config-react-app -D

# or

npm install -D eslint-config-react-app
```

Comment: you have the right answer: see https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/8#issuecomment-732536482

Comment: That works for me and  added --force

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue. I did these steps and it worked.

Install it as a dependency

```
npm i eslint-config-react-app
```

then in your root folder, create a file name **.eslintrc.json** and add this code in that file

```
  "extends": "react-app"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use yarn:

1- Delete: node_modules and yarn.lock 
2- Run: yarn install

Note: For npm should be the same approach.

Answer (score 3):

I was going through the same tutorial and came across the same problem. I figured out a few things:

The package `eslint-config-react` is outdated. It hasn't been updated in 4 years, so I uninstalled that and instead installed (as a devDependency) `eslint-config-airbnb`. There are other eslint config packages, but Airbnb's style guide I heard is very popular. Then in my eslintrc file I replaced `"extends": "react"` to `"extends": "airbnb"` :

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is the `eslint-config-react` package.

Answer (score 3):

Leaving this here for future reference:

In my case this was happening because I was using Lerna and it was hoisting up some of the necessary dependencies. Adding `nohoist` option to the `lerna.json` file resolved the issue for me:

```json
"nohoist": [
  "*react*",
  "*react*/**",
  "*react-native*",
  "*react-native*/**"
],
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Yarn 2(berry)

Add nodeLinker: node-modules in your .yarnrc.yml file

As specified in https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install

Answer (score 1):

If you cloned the repo from GitHub or any other version control system, try adding this file [.eslintrc.json](https://github.com/microverseinc/linters-config/blob/master/react-redux/.eslintrc.json) to your root folder. Don't forget the `.` at the beginning.

The first answer works like a charm as well. Just thought I would add mine as well.

Comment: I realized this works if the code had linters.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same issue.

- I deleted package-lock.json and node_modules
- ran 'npm install'

It worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue as well.
If anyone finds themselves in this predicament and you are forking a project, delete the package-lock resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

The **most voted answer** *by "Aryan Pitliya"* was the answer but didn't work **until** I downloaded latest eslint version.

So the **solution** for me was:

```
npm i eslint@latest
```

**THEN**

```
npm i eslint-config-react-app -D
```

Answer (score 0):

For fixing this issue you need to run this **command** in your project folder.
First step:

```
yarn set version berry
```

After run that, one file and folder will be generated in your local folder (Project folder) :

- .yarnrc.yml(file)
- .yarn(folder)

Second step: Add **nodeLinker: node-modules** in your .yarnrc.yml file

Third step: run this command `yarn install`

Finally run `yarn start`

**Tip** : This approach is useful when you want to migrate from yarn 1.x to 2.x or 3x or higher.

Answer (score 0):

even I had this issue, listing down steps to solve this issue.

1. First remove node modules and install node modules again.
2. Then I had a issue while I run npm run build, I was getting **react-scripts not found**. So I installed react-scripts using npm
3. Then I had this issue **failed to load config react-app to extend form**. I fixed it using

> npm add eslint-config-react-app

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same error when I was trying to deploy my create-react-app template to Vercel.

1. Deleting yarn.lock file
2. (On Vercel Dashboard) Overriding build command from auto to "npm run build"
3. (On Vercel Dashboard) Overriding install command from auto to "npm install"

helped me to deploy successfully.

Answer (score -2):

After getting the message "Failed to load config “react-app” to extend from...
I removed the following lines from package.json:

```
    "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
```

And it worked