# Failed to load config "react-app" to extend from. Referenced from: C:\\package.json

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts, prettier-eslint

**package.json**

"eslintConfig": {
"extends": [
"react-app",
"react-app/jest"
]
},

Comment: What's the error? you are not getting any feedback from eslint? if so what IDE are you using?

Comment: Some fixes here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63912721/failed-to-load-config-react-to-extend-from

Answer (score 4):

I just have the same error: for some reason, your `react-scripts` package is too old (mine was `1.1.5`). Find and change it in `package.json` to a more up-to-date version, say `4.0.3`, then run `npm update` to solve the issue.